# Alias memory in C

Tags: c, linux, memory, posix

If I have a rope-like datastructure such as this:

```
struct rope {
  struct { char *buf; size_t len; } *segments;
  size_t len;
}
```

Is there a way to map each segment's buffer contiguously into a virtual memory space, without copying? My usecase is to convert the rope to a string in the most efficient way possible.

Here's an example of how it would be used:

```
char *s = rope_flatten(r);
printf("%s\n", s);
r.segments[0].buf[4] = 'x';
printf("%s\n", s); // The 5th character is now replaced with 'x'
```

Needless to say, the buffers (at least, the bit that's mapped) would not be NUL terminated.

I understand this is probably incredibly platform-specific. If there's something POSIX-compliant that would be awesome. If not, Linux is my primary target and I can fall back to malloc and memcpy if it's not supported.

Comment: You need to allocate a large block of memory (malloc is fine for this) then allocate your buffers from that using your own logic. however, depending on the size of the buffers you may not gain much from doing this. E.g. if they are typically more than say 256 bytes then you may gain very little.

Comment: Such approach works quite well once you have fixed-size segments (so you can use @Ben recommendation then). Unfortunately, for variable-length segments the only way to avoid copying is to treat the segments as read-only once you've allocated them (so you don't have to move tail segments once middle one was shrink or expanded).

Comment: @Ben that kind of defeats the point of using a rope. Ropes allow efficient insertion and deletion, whereas a contiguous buffer doesn't.

Comment: You missed where I said "then allocate your buffers from that". My point is you don't have to do anything platform-specific to get a large chunk of memory, malloc will do it.

Comment: That's not quite what I mean. I want to be able to create a char array from multiple other char arrays without copying them, kind of like how `mmap` allows you to create a memory buffer from a file without copying data from that file (until you access the section of memory that corresponds to part of the file)

Comment: your question is not clear, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member

Comment: @Stargateur yeah, it's difficult to explain what I want clearly. There's probably some terminology I don't know that could help me explain it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a perfect world, you could create your rope as usual and remap each segment once again, so you have a second view where they are contiguous. If you edit a segment, no problems, it's mirrored to the other view. If you enlarge a segment, the buffer is transparently updated.

Couple of problems make this unfeasible though:

- Granularity with virtual memory isn't bytewise but pagewise, usually 4KiB and they are mapped as a whole. Your code units are probably a tad smaller than that.
- Adding and removing segments will still require page table modification
- Having to call into the kernel to update mappings when modifying will easily dwarf any performance benefits you hope to gain.
- Portability problems: APIs are OS-specific. MMU is required. Funny effects when coupled with VIVT caches

---

There are still use cases for mapping multiple views into an address space though, namely when the data changes but not the data *structure*, like with a ring buffer:

Normally, you would have to implement your wrap around logic in software, but if you remap the ring buffer's page(s) once more directly after, you got yourself a ring buffer you can just `memcpy` on. GNU Radio employs this mechanism and has a nice blog post on it:
https://www.gnuradio.org/blog/buffers/

The blog post made me curious and so I reimplemented the mechanism for Linux, Windows and macOS in [libvas](https://github.com/a3f/libvas/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=vas_ringbuf_t%20*vas_ringbuf_alloc&type=). Check it out if you like.